# how to toggle div inside update panel using javascript. asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I have a dropdownlist and a div inside update panel. I want to toggle div using javascript on dropdownlist selection change that is inside update panel. but it is not working.

```
function DistrictChange() {
        debugger;
        var ddldistrict = document.getElementById('<%=DDLDistrict.ClientID %>');
        var dvOther = document.getElementById('<%=divOthrDistrict.ClientID %>');
        if (ddldistrict.options[ddldistrict.selectedIndex].text == 'Other') {
            dvOther.style.display == 'block';

        }
        else {
            dvOther.style.display == 'none';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please share you code snippets which do it (even if it fails)

Comment: dvOther.style.display == 'none';
Must be
 dvOther.style.display = 'none';

Comment: @2GDev: thank you very much, how should i mark this as answer. there is no option.

Comment: I've added the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code :

```
dvOther.style.display == 'none';
```

== is compare statement.

Use this for assignment :

```
dvOther.style.display = 'none';
```